# Combine different date fields to a single Timestamp column in pyspark

Tags: datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

If the dataframe is like below:

| year | month | day | weekday | hour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | January | 1 | Sunday | 0 |
| 2018 | September | 22 | Saturday | 11 |

Then I need to add another column with values of type timestamp like the following:

```
2017-01-01 00:00:00
2018-09-22 11:00:00
```

I'm trying `unix_timestamp` after concatenating the fields into string type but not working.

Comment: could you please share the piece of code you tried? it's possible that you're not using the correct datetime formatters

Answer (score 1):

you can `concat` the elements into a string and use `to_timestamp` (or `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())`) with the appropriate [datetime pattern](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html).

here's the example

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('ts', 
               func.to_timestamp(func.concat_ws(' ', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour'), 
                                 'yyyy MMMM d H'
                                 )
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +----+---------+---+--------+----+-------------------+
# |year|month    |day|weekday |hour|ts                 |
# +----+---------+---+--------+----+-------------------+
# |2017|January  |1  |Sunday  |0   |2017-01-01 00:00:00|
# |2018|September|22 |Saturday|11  |2018-09-22 11:00:00|
# +----+---------+---+--------+----+-------------------+
```

Comment: It has worked. Thanks a lot